# Loops for calculating vegetation indices for multiple temporal images and each image have multiple bands

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, loop, vegetation-index

I have 64 TIFF files of different dates, each date has 4 bands (123 and 4 for B, G R and NIR). I am trying to develop a Vegetation index for each date image. This is how the images in my folder are

```
[1] "20171106.tif"     "20171106.tif.ovr" "20171113.tif"     "20171113.tif.ovr" "20171121.tif"     "20171121.tif.ovr" ........................................
 [64] "20171208.tif"
```

I used this command to process one single date image to get my index

```
st <- stack("20171106.tif")
br <- brick(st)
gcvi20171106 <- (br[[4]]/br[[2]])-1
plot(gcvi20171106)
```

But if I have to do it 64 times by manually changing the names its tedious.

I tried this loop

```
setwd("D:\\AP\\all_images\\")
lst <- list.files()
lngth <- length(lst)
rlist <- lapply(lst, raster)
for (i in 1:64){
  stk <- stack(rlist[i])
  brik[i] <- brick(stk[i])
  gcvi[i] <- (brik[[4]]/brik[[2]])-1
  }
```

I am new to loops. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to write a [function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/function.html) and apply it across all of your datasets using [`lapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html). For example:

```
require(raster)

# Define the input and output workspaces
inws <- '/path/to/input_workspace'
outws <- '/path/to/output_workspace'

# Get a list of tif files from inws
files <- list.files(inws, pattern = "*.tif", full.names = TRUE)

# Function to calculate GCVI veg index and write to raster
gcvi <- function(path, nir_band = 4, green_band = 2){
  img <- stack(path)
  nir <- img[[nir_band]]
  green <- img[[green_band]]
  vi <- (nir/green) - 1

  writeRaster(vi, file.path(outws, paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(path)), '_gcvi.tif', sep = "")))
}

# Apply the function across all files in inws
lapply(files, gcvi)
```

Comment: Many thanks, your code worked.